# Ruby/Selenium: How do I access the error code and message of Selenium errors?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I've set up some code to intentionally fail:

```
begin
  puts PageRatings.new(url: 'heckety').to_a
rescue StandardError => error
  binding.pry
end
```

When I enter pry, I see that:

```
> error.class
=> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError
```

I can see that `error` contains a code and a message:

```
> error
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609545 (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64)>
```

But how do I access the values of the code and message? Running `ls pry` I see that the following methods are available:

```
Exception#methods: 
  ==  backtrace  backtrace_locations  cause  exception  full_message  inspect  message  respond_to?  set_backtrace  to_s
```

But none of those methods return or unable me to get the message or codes separately. Is there a particular way to get at error codes/messages in Ruby?

Comment: what do `cause` and `message` return? You might be able to access that information from `cause` but most like you will have to parse the message string since  `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError` is just a `StandardError` nothing special appears to be retained

Comment: `cause` returns nil and `message` returns: `"unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"Cannot navigate to invalid URL\"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.80)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609545 (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64)"`

Comment: You could try `require 'json'; JSON.parse(error.message[/{.*}/]) #=> {"code"=>-32000, "message"=>"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}`. Then use as a standard `Hash`; however I cannot guarantee every message looks like this so additional error handling could be required

Comment: Hi, If you ready to use Ruby Selenium binding, then go for WATIR which is nice wrapper for Ruby Selenium binding.